# Build roulette using jQuery and CSS3 rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to build a roulette to be controlled by the mouse, I'm not using canvas or svg but only CSS3 rotation and some jQuery.

What I want to achieve is when the mouse is over the roulette and he is clicked and holds down, I want the user to be able to rotate the wheel when he moves the mouse up and down.
I'm using the `event.offsetY` to get the position of the mouse and according to this position I'm moving the roulette with or against the clock.

The problem is that I think the mouse offset position is changing according to the rotation of the wheel, is their a way to keep the mouse offset position "real" with the document?

-Or-

Someone know a better idea to accomplish that?

Please see the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/MZxgp/ (works on chrome only)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a overlay div that doesn't move to capture the mouse events (see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MZxgp/))

I hope this helps